# Openpyxl no longer shipped with OSGeo4W in QGIS3.28 (Windows)

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w

I just upgraded QGIS from 3.22 to 3.28 and it seems geopandas' read_excel() is no longer working when running it via the QGIS-Console / OSGEO4W-Shell due to Openpyxl missing.
Is anyone encountering the same issue / is this intentional?

I cannot simply install the package myself as I'm on a corporate device and until now everything I needed was shipped with QGIS.

Windows 10 Pro 22H2 (19045.3324)
QGIS 3.28.9

Comment: pip install from the python console should run in user mode and won't need administrative permission, better to check with your IT to be safe

Comment: pip installation is not possible for me due to firewall configuration. I need to find out wether it's intended that openpyxl is no longer shipped with QGIS/OSGEO4W so or if it will return.